# {{block type...}} in CMS not visible in frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, cms-block, whitelist

I use Magento 1.9.2.3 and I have a problem when I insert this code inside a CMS block:

```
{{block type="filterproducts/featured_home_list" name="latest_list" product_count="10" template="filterproducts/list.phtml"}}
```

This block is not shown in the frontend, I always see a white space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `filterproducts/featured_home_list` block entry in  whitelist table. To do so -

> Navigate to `Magento Admin > System > Permissions > Blocks` and click on  `Add New Block` button. On next screen enter your block type i.e. `filterproducts/featured_home_list` in **`Block Name`** field and set `Is Allowed` to `Yes`. After clear cache your block will be render.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Any time, happy coding .... :)